# AndroidX with BindingAdapter

Tags: kotlin, android-databinding, androidx, android-binding-adapter

I'm having some issues getting my BindingAdapter to work in my new app.

I'm always getting the following error:

```
****/ data binding error ****msg:Cannot find the setter for attribute 'visible' with parameter type boolean
```

This is my BindingAdapter:

```
object BindingAdapters {

@set:BindingAdapter("visible")
@JvmStatic
var View.visible
    get() = visibility == View.VISIBLE
    set(value) {
        visibility = if (value) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
    }
}
```

This is the view having the view in XML generating the problem:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDescription"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/item_horizontal_margin_large"
        android:text="@{viewModel.item.description}"
        visible="@{viewModel.showGroup}"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/ctvDivision"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

This is a new project, so I started with Android X and didn't need to do the migration.

I have this line in the build.grade:

```
annotationProcessor 'androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler:3.4.0-alpha09'
```

and I'm using gradle 3.2.11.

I'm not sure if this is needed, but this is the code where I'm inflating my binding:

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    setHasOptionsMenu(true)

    binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
            layoutInflater,
            R.layout.fragment_good,
            container,
            false
    )

    val view = binding?.root
    binding?.viewModel = viewModel

    return view
}
```

All the other standard databinding stuff works. As soon as I try setting up a BindingAdapter it fails.

I've read on SO that some people claimed databinding didn't work properly with X. But those were posts from october, and there were people claiming it worked perfectly for them in the same post.

Am I forgetting something stupid or is it really not yet working with X?

Comment: I'm using AndroidX and I tested your BindingAdapter in my project and it works fine. In my app build gradle I have `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'` and `kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:3.3.0-alpha11"` defined and in my gradle.properties: `android.useAndroidX=true android.enableJetifier=true android.databinding.enableV2=true`. Also I'm setting the lifecycle owner in the fragment: `binding.setLifecycleOwner(this)`. Also obviously in the build.gradle you have to define `dataBinding { enabled = true }`. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reproduce the problem in small new project using Kotlin (1.3.30), AndroidX, DataBinding and Gradle 3.4.0

Firstly, Kotlin doesn't work with the `annotationProcessor` and must be replaced by Kotlin Annotation Processing Tool: `kapt` with `kotlin-kapt` plugin.
[Kotlin documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/kapt.html)

Then in Gradle 3.1.0-alpha06, Google has included a new version of the data binding compiler enable by default since Gradle 3.2.
So you don't need to use `databinding-compiler` dependency (it is integrated).
[Android Developer documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/start.html#preview-compiler)

But even integrated, it always need of *kapt*.
So, add `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'` at top of your `build.gradle` *app* file and remove the `androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler` dependency, should solves the problem. (It has worked for me)

Comment: I cannot test right now but think you are right on the spot

Answer (score -1):

I ran into the same issue. If your binding adapters are written in Kotlin (instead of Java), then you can no longer pass Java primitive boolean variables to them (or any primitive Java types). Change your viewModel.showGroup to either a Java.lang.Boolean or preferably, a Kotlin Boolean.

I've also noticed, that if you use an boolean expression in the data binding expression, such as `visible="@{viewModel.showGroup &amp;&amp; true}"`, then that outputs a Java primitive boolean and is no longer compatible with Kotlin binding adapters.